# Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, log4j

I have created a wrapper for logging over log4j extending HandlerInterceptorAdapter keeping build type maven project. I am using this project as an external JAR in my Spring Boot application. Using Logger in my controllers. I have written JUnits for it which are working fine but got exception during mvn install.

DemoLogger is an interface exposing functions to log. DemoLogger is part of maven project which is an external jar.

**Controller**

```
@RestController @RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class DemoController {

    private DemoLogger logger = LoggerFactory.createLog(DemoController.class);

    @GetMapping("/demo")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getString() {
        logger.info("This is test debug");
        return new ResponseEntity("Hello World", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**JUnit**

```java
public class DemoControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks private DemoController demoController;

    @Before public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test public void shouldReturnString()throws Exception {
        final String body = demoController.getString().getBody().toString();
        assertEquals("Hello World", body);
    }
}
```

**Error Log**

```
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'demoController' of type 'class dev.example.controller.DemoController'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : dev/example2/logger/factory/LoggerFactory

at dev.example.controller.DemoControllerTest.setup(DemoControllerTest.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/example2/logger/factory/LoggerFactory
```

Comment: Use @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) in the test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems more like a Maven problem that Mockito.

Most likely you are using that jar without specifying it in your pom as a dependency.

It works in your local IDE as most likely you added it manually to the classpath.

Try to install that jar in your local .m2 (or ideally on your company Nexus or something similar) and then run the build:

```
mvn install:install-file
```

More info [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).